# Creating tfrecord with audio sample, extracted from video in python

Tags: python

This code is for creating tfrecords which is tensorflows standard input format for keeping audios and labels taken from video samples.This file is given as input for training in neural network.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-   

import menpo
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import os

from io import BytesIO
from pathlib import Path
from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip
from menpo.visualize import progress_bar_str, print_progress
from moviepy.audio.AudioClip import AudioArrayClip

root_dir = Path('/home/user/Desktop/PROJECT/Multimodal-Emotion-Recognition-master/RECOLA') #Where RECOLA is located
portion_to_id = dict(
train = [1], # 25
valid = [70, 71],
test  = [80, 81] # 54, 53
) #samples taken

def get_samples(subject_id): #location of arousal and valence files and appropriate video sample
  arousal_label_path = root_dir / 'ratings_individual/arousal/{}.csv'.format(subject_id)
 valence_label_path = root_dir / 'ratings_individual/valence/{}.csv'.format(subject_id)

 clip = VideoFileClip(str(root_dir /"Video_recordings_MP4/{}.mp4".format(subject_id)))

  subsampled_audio = clip.audio.set_fps(16000)

  audio_frames = []

  for i in range(1, 7501): #extract audio sample
     try:
       time = 0.04 * i

       audio = np.array(list(subsampled_audio.subclip(time - 0.04, time).iter_frames()))
       audio = audio.mean(1)[:640]

       audio_frames.append(audio.astype(np.float32))
     except ValueError:
       print('Not float') 
       quit() 
      try:   
       arousal = np.loadtxt(str(arousal_label_path), delimiter=',')[:+1][1:]
       valence = np.loadtxt(str(valence_label_path), delimiter=',')[:+1][1:]


      return audio_frames, np.dstack([arousal, valence])[0].astype(np.float32) #return audio frames
     except ValueError:
      print('problem')



def get_jpg_string(im):
# Gets the serialized jpg from a menpo `Image`.
   fp = BytesIO()
   menpo.io.export_image(im, fp, extension='jpg')
   fp.seek(0)
   return fp.read()

def _int_feauture(value):
   return tf.train.Feature(int64_list=tf.train.Int64List(value=[value]))

def _bytes_feauture(value):
   return tf.train.Feature(bytes_list=tf.train.BytesList(value=[value]))

def serialize_sample(writer, subject_id):


  subject_name = 'P{}'.format(subject_id)
  print(subject_name)
  print(get_samples)
  #repeat for each sample
  for i, (audio, label) in enumerate(zip(*get_samples(subject_name))):

     example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature={
                'sample_id': _int_feauture(i),
                'subject_id': _int_feauture(subject_id),
                'label': _bytes_feauture(label.tobytes()),
                'raw_audio': _bytes_feauture(audio.tobytes()),
            })) #extract sample_id,subject_id,label and raw_audio

     writer.write(example.SerializeToString())
     del audio, label



def main(directory):
   print('In Main')
   for portion in portion_to_id.keys():
    print(portion)

    for subj_id in print_progress(portion_to_id[portion]):


     temp = (directory / 'tf_records' / portion / '{}.tfrecords'.format(subj_id)
      ).as_posix() #display sample
     print(temp)

     writer = tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter(
      (directory / 'tf_records' / portion / '{}.tfrecords'.format(subj_id)
      ).as_posix()) #write to tfrecords

     serialize_sample(writer, subj_id)

if __name__ == "__main__":
  print("Calling Main")
  main(Path('/home/user/Desktop/PROJECT/Multimodal-Emotion-Recognition-master/records')) #save tfrecord
```

This code raises an error and terminates.I have given all paths to locate input video.

> Error

```
   for i, (audio, label) in enumerate(zip(*get_samples(subject_name))):
   TypeError: zip() argument after * must be an iterable, not NoneType
```

Why do I get this error?

Answer (score 0):

do you have following video/audio files in your test, train and valid folders:

```
train = P1.mp4
valid = P70.mp4 , P71.mp4
test  = P80.mp4 , P81.mp4   ??
```

because the code: zip(*get_samples(subject_name)) seems to unable to fetch the data: Nonetype!